# setInterval() only running function once

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to periodically query a PHP script for new messages. To do so, I'm using the setInterval() function and AJAX.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var queryInterval = 1000; /* How fast we query for new messages */

    setInterval(getMessages(), queryInterval);

    function getMessages() {
        console.log("tick");
    }

});
```

However, when I look at the Javascript console, I'm only seeing "tick" once. I've made sure that the console doesn't ignore any more logs of the same strings, so if the code was working properly it should show "tick" in the console every second.

Anyone know what could be going wrong here?

Comment: there was another question just like this like an hour ago.

Comment: getMessages() should be getMessages

Comment: @32bitkid: Questions about `setTimout` and `setInterval` are quite common.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change:

```
setInterval(getMessages(), queryInterval);
```

To:

```
setInterval(getMessages, queryInterval);
```

Comment: @qwertymk but i want to pass an argument to that function what do i do  

this.intervall = setInterval(window.External(this),intervally);

PLease HELP

Comment: @JamilHneini so do: `setInterval(function() { getMessages(arg) } , queryInterval);`

Comment: @qwertymk I am working with a function that is an object constructor I have a function that take the this object and do something I need to run that function in an intervall as if I used function(){ getMessages(this) ,1900); this is considered as window not the object constructor

Comment: @JamilHneini Try opening a new question

Comment: @qwertymk Done here is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819677/pass-this-object-inside-a-constructor-to-a-setintervall/18819692?noredirect=1#18819692

Answer (score 9):

Actually, `setInterval` isn't running `getMessages` at all (not even once). `setInterval` expects a *reference* to a function, but you're executing the `getMessages` function *immediately* and passing its return value to `setInterval` (which is `undefined`). That's what the parens after `getMessage` do.

Pass a reference to `setInterval` like this:

```
setInterval(getMessages, queryInterval);
```

If this is the only place that `getMessages` is used, then you could also write it like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("tick");
}, queryInterval);
```

Comment: @qwertymk is certainly right but +1 for this because it more clearly explains how setInterval works under the hood.

Comment: @jsh - Right, what I don't like about answers like the one that was accepted is that, while correct, it doesn't teach much. Knowing the difference between referring to a function vs. executing it is a very, very basic, fundamental part of the language.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `()` after `getMessage`

Answer (score 2):

This **calls** `getMessages`, not schedules it. Remove the parenthesis.

```
setInterval(getMessages(), queryInterval);

setInterval(getMessages, queryInterval);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your code line:

```
setInterval(getMessages(), queryInterval);
```

The `setInterval` function requires you to pass the reference to your callback function.

When you pass `getMessages(),` You are actually calling the function and passing its returning object to the `setInterval` function.

So just change your line to:

```
setInterval(getMessages, queryInterval);
```

and it will works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Although others have already covered this ground above, both window.setTimeout() and window.setInterval() require function *references*. Your code provides, instead, the *return value* from a *function invocation*.

When you wish to call, or invoke, a JavaScript function, you write, as expected:

DoMyfunction();

The JavaScript engine will execute that function upon encountering that line.

However, what setTimeout() and setInterval() require, is a *reference to the function object* corresponding to your function. Which you obtain via the following, and similar means:

myFunc = DoMyFunction;

That line copies a reference to the *function object* corresponding to DoMyFunction() into a new variable. Which you can then pass to setInterval() and setTimeout(), viz:

discard = window.setTimeout(myFunc, 1000);

That line above will direct the JavaScript engine to execute your intended function (namely DoMyFunction()) once, after 1 second has elapsed, and:

discard = window.setInterval(myFunc, 1000);

will direct the JavaScript engine to execute your intended function repeatedly, once every second.

You could, of course, achieve the same effect, without using a new variable, simply as follows:

discard = window.setTimeout(DoMyFunction, 1000);

etc.

If, however, you make the mistake of using:

discard = window.setTimeout(DoMyFunction(), 1000);

what happens instead is that DoMyFunction() is executed, and any return parameter arising therefrom is *then* passed to the window.setTimeout() function. Since window.setTimeout() is expecting a function object reference to be passed here, and instead receives whatever your function returns (or *undefined* if your function returns nothing), then the internal checking performed by setTimeout() (and setInterval()) will reveal that it hasn't received a function object reference here, and simply abort silently.

A far more insidious bug, of course, could arise if DoMyFunction() actually **does** return a valid function object! If you've written DoMyFunction() to do this, then **that** function object will be passed to setTimeout() instead, and **that** function will be run! Of course, you could use this intentionally, and write your DoMyFunction() as a closure, returning the **actual** function you want setTimeout() to execute as a function object return parameter, and if you use **that** approach, then the form:

discard = window.setTimeout(DoMyFunction(), 1000);

will no longer be erroneous.

Remember, **every** JavaScript function you write in your code, when that code is parsed, is associated with a *function object* by the JavaScript engine. To execute the function, use:

DoMyFunction();

To reference the *function object* instead, use:

DoMyFunction;

Those () can make a *huge* amount of difference according to context, as a result of JavaScript taking this approach to differentiating between a *function object reference* and a *function execution instruction*.