# setInterval is only running one time?

Tags: jquery, animation, carousel, setinterval

JSFiddle is here...

http://jsfiddle.net/Vd8PJ/10/

All right. I'm trying to create a JQuery carousel to display some images of different widths. To help accomplish this, I'm trying to produce a seamless, unending slide to the right on an unordered list containing images. I plan to put images  that have passed the threshold behind the rest with the .before property so that it will continue forever. However, I have three problems.

The first problem is that if my JS looks like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    function gallery () {
    $("#image").animate({"margin-left":"200px"}, 3000);
    }
setInterval(gallery, 3000);
});
```

It waits 3 seconds, and it only runs once. I did look around to see if I could fix the only running once problem, and I found this...

[setInterval() only running function once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732191/setinterval-only-running-function-once)

And many other questions like it. Always it is the same thing. They are calling the function like this...

```
setInterval(gallery(), 3000);
```

in setInterval, instead of like this...

```
setInterval(gallery, 3000);
```

So, I know that cannot be the solution. Considering my function already has no parentheses following it, and is being called the correct way. (I think.)

So, logically I tried to fix the next problem, the three second delay. I wrote this...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#image").animate({"margin-left":"200px"}, 3000);
    function gallery () {
        $("#image").animate({"margin-left":"200px"}, 3000);
    }
    setInterval(gallery, 3000);
});
```

Now it runs instantly when the page loads, however since setInterval was only running once before, I would assume I would get two occurrences of...

```
$("#image").animate({"margin-left":"200px"}, 3000);
```

One that was running on load, and the other being run from the "gallery" function by setInterval. This however is not the case. It runs instantly but I only get one occurrence.

My final problem does not have anything to do with setInterval, but I figure I would kill two birds with one stone. Because my unordered list hasa width of 9,999 pixels, does that mean even if I run the animation continuously, eventually I will run out of element to move?

Comment: animate is your problem here, use instead "+=200" and set logic for last image when reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is running only once

```
$("#image").animate({"margin-left":"200px"}, 3000);
```

When the function runs for the first time the `margin-left:200px` is already set to the attribute provided.

So the next time it runs, there is no change in the `margn-left` property. So it looks static

I think you are looking for

```
$("#image").animate({"margin-left":"+=200"}, 3000);
```

Using **+=** will  increment the value that is provided every time the function runs.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vd8PJ/12/)**

Comment: Yep, that's what I was missing. Thank you very much.