# setInterval in setTimout only firing once in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As the title states this only seems to fire once. i need it to run continually.

Code inside my controller:

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.test();
        console.log('starting test');
        // check and update dates every minute (hopefully language will be in the bridge)
        $scope.testInterval = setInterval($scope.test(), 1000);
    }, 2000);

    $scope.test = function () {
        console.log('test');
    };
```

Console outputs:

```
test
starting test
test
```

And then nothing. Just stops working.

Comment: Should be closed as a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732191/setinterval-only-running-function-once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call scope .test() in the setinterval line. You need to pass the function instead of the result of the function.

```
$scope.testInterval = setInterval($scope.test(), 1000);
```

becomes

```
$scope.testInterval = setInterval($scope.test, 1000);
```

Also since setInterval fires the immediately the first time you don't need the extra $scope.test() before setting the interval.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling the function, you should rather use

```
$scope.testInterval = setInterval($scope.test, 1000);
```

the difference you should note here is that $scope.test is without brackets `()`, as you want to call this function and not the executed return value of this function.

If you already write `$scope.test()` it will return undefined and your interval will not run (as your setInterval function argument is undefined). If you write `$scope.test` your interval will invoke the test function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$interval` instead of `setInterval`.

```
var interval = $interval(function() {
  console.log('say hello');
}, 1000);
```

If you want to stop it:

```
$interval.cancel(interval);
```